# I want to move my old pictures to iCloud to free up iPhone storage space (iPhone already at full capacity)

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos

Basically I want to remove these pictures from my phone onto the cloud.
My purpose is to free up local storage as much as possible (for Apps and other stuff).

I'm doing this for my relative's phone, I don't use an iPhone. I have bought the the necessary storage, but I don't want to make a mistake and lose the photos.

Answer (score 3):

**iCloud is a syncing service, so any photos you delete on the phone will also get deleted in iCloud.** This is obviously not what you want.

You can configure the phone to automatically manage local storage though by opening Settings, scrolling down to Photos and selecting the "Optimize iPhone storage" option. This will store the full resolution photos in iCloud while just keeping a low-res version on the phone itself. If required (for editing or sharing) the full-res version will get downloaded again automatically.

See [Apple's support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204264) for more details on how to setup and use iCloud Photos.